# What is the Tomcat equivalent of JBoss' *-ds.xml?

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, datasource

In JBoss one can define a datasource with a *-ds.xml.

Is there an equivalent thing or procedure in Tomcat ?

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/UsingDataSources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomcat has several possibilities for configuring data sources. The main difference is if the data source should be available globally or just for a specific web application.

You can find all you need in the [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html). Why didn't you look there right away?

Comment: Tks for posting your link. Initially, I read this link http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html and left out the JDBC Datasources. I thought it wasn't the purpose of my search.

Answer (score 2):

In you configure the data source in context.xml file. Each webapp has one in META-INF folder. A data source will look like this:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MyDS" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="root" password=""
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"
          maxActive="8" 
        />
```

You can also define a data source in the conf/context.xml file. In that case the data source will be available in all applications. You can reference a data source (e.g. in persistence.xml) like this:

```
<jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/JuddiDS</jta-data-source>
```

Comment: This solution is OK. But I have to embed within the application its connection parameters. Each time I deploy in a new environment, I have to package the application specially. I'd much like to see those specific environment parameters bundled outside the app pretty like the `*-ds.xml` mecanism.

Comment: I've already wrote that you can place the same definition in [Tomcat Dir]/conf/context.xml. In that case the resource will be visible to all applications.

Comment: Yep I've already read this option. But it's not OK for me. I'm really searching a solution identical to the one offered by JBoss.